# Add default role to many-many relation in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two `Sequelize.js` models what are connected by many-to-many relation.

User:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const model = sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR,
            length: 60,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }
    });

    model.associate = models => {
        model.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
            hooks: true,
            through: 'user_roles'
        })
    };

    return model;
};
```

Role:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const model = sequelize.define('Role',
        {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: false,
                allowNull: false
            }
        }
    );

    model.associate = models => {
        model.belongsToMany(models.User, {
            hooks: true,
            through: 'user_roles'
        });
    };

    return model;
};
```

Table `user_roles` is created automatically.

How to set default role what will be inserted into `user_roles` while creating new `User`? Is there way to define it in models definition or I am just supposed to create `User` new user and then create relation in one transaction?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a model for the user_roles after creating that you have to set a hook inside your user model that will automatically insert roles in to your user_roles table.

This is how you can do it.

For Example :

**User Model**

```
const { hooks } = require('./user-role.hook');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const model = sequelize.define('User', {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR,
            length: 60,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, { hooks });

    model.associate = models => {
        model.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
            hooks: true,
            through: 'user_roles'
        })
    };

    return model;
};
```

**Hook file**

```
exports.hooks = {
    afterCreate: (User, payload) => {
        AddUserRole(User, payload);
    }
}

function AddUserRole(User, payload) {
    let InsertArr = {
        user_id: User._id,
        role_id: 1 // pass default role id

    }
    model.UserRole.create(InsertArr);
}
```

Comment: Nice and what if I need to do it in one transaction? Is it possible?

Comment: yes if you use transaction you have to call it after user creation in that case don't use hook.